# R - Get data from 2 specific columns to plot a polynomial regression

Tags: r

I am trying to use an excel file with multiple columns (30+), to plot a polynomial graph. I need two specific columns, Spend and Sales plotted together. However, as I am very new to the platform I am unable to find how you actually tell R to select those two specific columns and plot them. I tried different codes I saw online but none seemed to work for me. Any guide or good reading material place for beginners would be welcome as well.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ is my go-to resource to learn R.

Comment: Thanks that looks great :)